# Remove code-history of indexed website? Possible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, search-engine

Once the HTML/CSS/JS of a website has been indexed by google (and whatever else) is it then
completely impossible to erase that code-history of the website? I.E google caching, way back machine
ETC. Theres some things from a website I want to remove the history of but, thinkin it isn't possible?

Comment: It would be like trying to erase yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [a `robots.txt` file](http://www.robotstxt.org/) denying access to everything, and that will take your site (and likely its cached versions) out of Google and the Wayback Machine, but there are likely other sites that can archive your site that don't heed `robots.txt`. There's not much you can do about that besides asking the owners of the site to remove it.